# How to search an element in a table using pagination in selenium Web Driver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pagination

Hi i am facing problem in my script.I need to verify whether an element is present in the pagination table or not.
I write the below code but it is showing error and also loop is not working.Can anyone help me in my script?
This is my code and the error what i am getting:

//pagination of the table

```
    List<WebElement> allpages=d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='reportPagination_wrapper']//a"));
    System.out.println("Total page : "+allpages.size());

    if(allpages.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("pagination exist");

        //click on pagination link

        for(int i=0;i<=allpages.size();i++)
        {
            if(allpages.contains(flight_no))
            {
                System.out.println("record exists");

                break;
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("eleenmt no");
                allpages.get(i).click();
            }
            }               
        }

        }
```

Output: Total page : 13

```
   pagination exist

   eleenmt no
   eleenmt no
```

FAILED: search_basedon_flightno

The error:
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StaleElementReferenceException comes when the element is no longer available in the dom or has become stale. In order to correct it, you need to again fetch the elements and then operate on it.
For example in your case it should be:

```
List<WebElement> allpages=d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='reportPagination_wrapper']//a"));
    System.out.println("Total page : "+allpages.size());

    if(allpages.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("pagination exist");

        //click on pagination link

        for(int i=0;i<=allpages.size();i++)
        {
            allpages=d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='reportPagination_wrapper']//a"));
            if(allpages.contains(flight_no))
            {
                System.out.println("record exists");

                break;
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("eleenmt no");
                allpages.get(i).click();
            }
          }               
      }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you its working,.But showing again error as index out of bound.Why it is showing like that?

Comment: Because when you are fetching the elements again, there can be scenario that one element got removed, so due to which the size got decreased by one.